# Canvas Child in background

Tags: c#, wpf, back

I want to put a `Canvas` child to background.

For example: I have an `Ellipse` (child of canvas). When I add a rectangle on same coordinates I want to put it under ellipse.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ZIndex Attached property of the Canvas (Panel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex):

```
<Canvas>
    <Ellipse Canvas.ZIndex = "10" />
    <Rectangle Canvas.ZIndex = "5"/>
</Canvas>
```

Or you can reorder the child elements:

```
<Canvas>
    <Rectangle/>
    <Ellipse />
</Canvas>
```

In code:

```
Canvas.SetZIndex(newRectangle, 5);
Canvas.SetZIndex(oldEllipse, 10);
```